# Why do we use \ instead of the namespace?

Tags: laravel, namespaces

I am new to Laravel and I have seen that when we use `Query Builder` instead of `Eloquent` as is required we must add the namespace i.e. `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;` or `use DB;`(As it is mentioned in Aliases) inorder to use it, some people simply use `\DB` while writing a query.

Eg. `\DB->table('tasks')->where('id', 3)->get();`

What does `\` denote in namespacing convention or what does it mean here. While finding answers someone told me, `\` means `Global Namespace`, but if that's true what does it actually mean in this context? I used `\` in place of `App\Model_Name` and I got an error. Why s that so if `\` means Global Namespace?

Comment: The `aliases` array in app.php spoof a root (global) namespace I believe. That is why you **can** write a backslash in front of it.

Comment: @ThomasMoors I knew that instead of writing the entire namespace, we could write an Alias but `\` takes an Alias to the root, never knew that. Are you sure about that?

Comment: I am not sure about it

Comment: @ThomasMoors Thanks anyways, maybe I can search more on that line now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP has a trick for referring to classes that are located within the global namespace, we simply prefix them with a backward `(\)` slash.

With the leading backward `(\)` slash, PHP knows that we are referring to the **Class** in the global namespace, and instantiates that one.

You will have an error while using `(\)` when some classes have same **Class** names.

**Example:**

**Request** class has many namespaces `Illuminate\Support\Facades\Request` and `Illuminate\Http\Request` and when you are trying to use **Request** class for 
`Illuminate\Http\Request` class and you have defined `\Request` instead of using a namespace, the conflict will happen and you will get an error with no class found.

This is my belief. Hope this stuff will help you little to understand.

Comment: When you say, ` classes that are located within the global namespace`, could you tell me the location of those classes precisely, please?